# Run multiple "search and replace"

Tags: excel

I got a task at my work I am having some trouble with. It is a new job.

I got a Excel sheet with +3000 emails in a single column. All of these emails have some kind of typing error in them.

We made about 30 rules (search and replaces) which can help us solve the typing errors.

**It could be:**

- Find: gnail.com replace with: gmail.com
- Find: gmail.co replace with: gmail.com
- Find: autlook.com replace with: outlook.com

Is there any way I can set these rules up so Excel automatically runs all 30 search and replaces?

Comment: Record a macro of using find and replace and start from there. You'll need to incorporate a loop. Post the code you try.

Comment: 2 questions: 1) have you placed these 'rules' in column (wrong/correct)? 2) Is all errors only occuring after `@`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Modify and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim str As String

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            str = .Range("A" & i).Value

            If InStr(1, str, "gnail.com") <> 0 Then
                .Range("A" & i).Replace What:="gnail.com", Replacement:="gmail.com"
            ElseIf InStr(1, str, "gmail.co") <> 0 Then
                .Range("A" & i).Replace What:="gmail.co", Replacement:="gmail.com"
            ElseIf InStr(1, str, "autlook.com") <> 0 Then
                .Range("A" & i).Replace What:="autlook.com", Replacement:="outlook.com"
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i happening again and again... yesterday i get almost 10 down votes in a period of 3-4 hours for codes that are tested, works & get positive comments from the asker.